# What is the best way to implement a search in the pattern DAL?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, implementation, data-access-layer

I usually declare my DAL classes overwriting search methods whenever possible as the example below:

```
public class clsAsd {
    private AdConn oConn;

    public clsAsd(ref AdConn Connection) {
        oConn = Connection;
    }

    private string sqlSearch(string DocType, string Status, string Aaa) {
        return
            "    AND x.tp_doc = '" + DocType + "'\r\n" +
            "    AND x.co_status IN (" + Status + ")\r\n" +
            "    AND x.aaa = '" + Aaa + "'\r\n";
    }
    public List<clsQwe> search(string DocType, string Status, string Aaa, bool IncDel) {
        return search(sqlSearch(DocType, Status, Aaa), IncDel);
    }

    private string sqlSearch(string DocType, string Status, string Aaa, string Bbb) {
        string sSQL = sqlSearch(DocType, Status, Aaa) + (Bbb != "" ? "    AND x.bbb = '" + Bbb + "'\r\n" : "");
        return sSQL;
    }
    public List<clsQwe> search(string DocType, string Status, string Aaa, string Bbb, bool IncDel) {
        return search(sqlSearch(DocType, Status, Aaa, Bbb), IncDel);
    }

    private List<clsQwe> search(string Where, bool IncDel) {
        string sSQL;

        sSQL = "SELECT\r\n";
        sSQL += "    b.aaa, c.bbb, x.*\r\n";
        sSQL += "FROM asd x, qwe b, zxc c\r\n";
        sSQL += "WHERE x.www = b.www\r\n";
        sSQL += "    AND x.zzz = c.zzz\r\n";
        sSQL += Where;

        if (!IncDel) sSQL += "    AND x.del IS NULL\r\n";

        sSQL += "ORDER BY x.www";

        // Connection + Run SQL

        // List to get results
        List<clsQwe> lstRet = new List<clsQwe>();

        // Row to add in list
        clsQwe oX;

        while (oReader.Read()) {
            oX = new clsQwe();
            // Add all data
            lstRet.Add(oX);
        }

        // Return data
        return lstRet;
    }
}
```

My question is: is this a good practice?

I should use one method for each different search?
example:

```
public class clsAsd {
    private AdConn oConn;
    public clsAsd(ref AdConn Connection) { oConn = Connection; }

    public List<clsQwe> search1(string DocType, string Status, string Aaa, bool IncDel) { }
    public List<clsQwe> search2(string DocType, string Status, string Aaa, string Bbb, bool IncDel) { }
    public List<clsQwe> search3(string DocType, string Status, string Aaa, string Bbb, string Ccc, bool IncDel) { }

    private List<clsQwe> search(string Where, bool IncDel) { }
}
```

How could I improve this class?

I'm considering implementing only one search method that receives the class (clsQwe) as a parameter. I check each property of this class and create the where clause in accordance with properties populated.

This approach is interesting?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not. You are open for [sql-injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx), use parameterized queries.

Comment: I know this and I'm using Oracle commands on real implementation. My question is more how best to implement the search for my class? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve your classes, which work with db directly, you can use [ORM](http://nhforge.org/).